# 2019s way of accessing navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()

Tags: angular, getusermedia, zone.js, zonejs

I am currently developing an angular7-app, created it the standard way through CLI and started coding. 
Now I would like to record some audio which is no difficult thing in modern browsers. I am using the built-in browser functionalities of `getUserMedia()`. 
Now comes the problem: zone.js catches all calls to the `then()` callback and does not allow to execute the custom code inside.

BUT: There is the patch delivered with zone.js, so that this special callback is called: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/dist/zone-patch-user-media.js

Unfortunately, this refers to a depreciated implementation of `getUserMedia()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia). 
So this script does not work. I tried changing it but nothing works. The patch is called because `console.log()` is displayed and in the debugger, I can go through the function. I assume, that this might be a little change to execute the callback. In the debugger the callback is then again catched by a function in zone.js which, as I assume, should not be called when the patch works. My implementation is the same as here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(
function(stream) {
    /* use the stream */ 
}).catch(
function(err) { 
    /* handle the error */ 
});
```

So, what is the current way of getting the callback to work? Or am I getting the concept wrong? Or should I use some library from npm to record the audio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much as I know, `zone.js` should not cause problems if used with `navigator` methods, since they're well known and correctly patched. By the way, if you are sure of what you say, you can still use `zone.runOutsideAngular` to go out from a zone:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

yourMethod() {
  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(stream => console.log(stream))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  });

}
```

If then you want to re-enter a zone, you can call:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
  // again inside a zone
});
```

But be aware that you need it only if you want to continue an async flow. The sync code will keep being executed inside a zone:

```
yourMethod() {
  // this is inside a zone

  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(stream => {

        // this is outside a zone

        this.zone.run(() => {

           // and again inside a zone

        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  });

 // this is still inside a zone

}
```

Comment: When clicking through debugger the next call clearly goes to zone.js where a function like 'catchThen' (can't remember the name because I am currently not at work) is called. Something is going on there. But I will try your suggestion and get back. Is there something like `zone.goInsideAngular` what I should call at the end of my script?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had time to check it and your provided solution (going outside the zone) works well.

Comment: Appreciate for saving my day!, was all trying to fix this with webrtc that never worked,